# Calculating budget for employee hierarchy

Tags: c++

> You have to write a C++ program that reads in the employee hierarchy
>   of a company and computes a statistic called 'salary budget' for all
>   employees.
>
> For this problem, the 'salary budget' of any employee is defined as
>   follows:
>
> For employees who are not managers, the salary budget is same as their
>   salary For managers, the salary budget is the sum of his/her salary
>   and the salary budgets of all employees whose manager this employee
>   is. You have to print a list of all employees and their salary budget,
>   sorted in decreasing order of salary budget.
>
> For example, the input will be provided to you on the standard input
>   in this format:
>
> ```
> Vineel Phatak, 5200000, NOBODY
> Ajay Joshi, 2500000, Vineel Phatak
> Abhishek Chauhan, 1200000, Ajay Joshi
> Vijaya Mundada, 600000, Abhishek, Chauhan
> Rajan Gawli, 7000000, Vineel Phatak
> Sheila Rodrigues, 350000, Vineel Phatak
> ```
>
> Each line contains an employee name, a salary, and the name of the
>   boss of that employee - all separated by commas. The special name
>   NOBODY for boss indicates that this employee does not have a boss (and
>   is hence the CEO of the company). You can assume that there is only
>   one CEO in the company.
>
> For this input, your program should produce the following output:
>
> ```
> Vineel Phatak: 16850000
> Rajan Gawli: 7000000
> Ajay Joshi: 4300000
> Abhishek Chauhan: 1800000
> Vijaya Mundada: 600000
> Sheila Rodrigues: 350000
> ```

I was asked to code it.  What are the problems with this code? Since the input seemed open ended, I have made some assumptions written as comments in code.

I want to know if following assumptions for input are correct or could be done better

1. all empolyee names are unique
2. a managers entry comes before any of his/her subordinates in input

```cpp
class Employee
{
 private:
    QString name;
    QString mgrName;
    int salary;
    int budget;

 public:
    Employee()
    {
        name = QString();
        mgrName = QString();
        salary = 0;
        budget =0;
    }

    Employee(QString _name, QString _mgrName, int _salary):name(_name),
        mgrName(_mgrName), salary(_salary)
    {
        budget = 0;
    }
    const QString getName(){return name;}
    const QString getName() const{return name;}
    const int getSalary(){return salary;}
    void setBudget(const int value){budget = value;}
    const int getBudget(){return budget;}
    const int getBudget() const{return budget;}

    friend  bool operator < (const Employee & emp1, const Employee & emp2);


};

bool operator < (const Employee & emp1, const Employee & emp2)
{
    return (emp1.budget <= emp2.budget ? true : false);
}


int budget(QMultiMap< QString,  Employee > & heirarchy, const QString& mgrName)
{
    if(heirarchy.values(mgrName).size() ==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int empBudget = 0;

    QList<Employee> subordinate = heirarchy.values(mgrName);

    for(int i = 0; i < subordinate.size(); i++)
    {
        empBudget += budget(heirarchy, subordinate.at(i).getName());
    }

    return empBudget;
}

void calculateBudget(QMultiMap< QString,  Employee > & heirarchy, QVector<Employee> & employees)
{
    Employee emp;
    foreach(emp, employees)
    {
        int bgt = budget(heirarchy, emp.getName());
        emp.setBudget( emp.getSalary() + bgt );
    }
    qSort(employees.begin(), employees.end(), qGreater<Employee>());

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Assumptions about input
    // 1. read from a file with comma separated entry for each employee and new line after each entry
    // 2. all empolyee names are unique
    // 3. a managers entry comes before any of his/her subordinates in input
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString filename(argv[1]);

    if(filename.isEmpty())
        qDebug() << "No input file.";

    QVector<Employee> employees;
    // this map contains employee name who is manager as key and his team in list
    // multimap is a map with many value having same key or QMap< QString, QList < Employees> >
    QMultiMap< QString,  Employee > heirarchy;
    QFile inputFile(filename);
    int i = 0;
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
         QTextStream in(&inputFile);
         while ( !in.atEnd() )
         {
             QString line = in.readLine();
             QStringList paramList = line.split(",");
             Employee emp(paramList.at(0), paramList.at(1), paramList.at(2).toInt());
             if( i == 0)
             {
                //root or CEO
                 heirarchy.insert("NOBODY", emp);
                 i++;
             }
             else
             {
                 heirarchy.insert(paramList.at(1), emp);
             }
             employees.push_back(emp);
         }
         inputFile.close();
    }


    calculateBudget(heirarchy, employees);


    qDebug()<< " Employess in descending order of their budget:";
    for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug()<< employees.at(i).getName()<<" budget is "<<employees.at(i).getBudget();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I added a section relating to assumptions, fyi, if it helps

Answer (score 5):

**Boolean Operators**

When you make a class specific Boolean operator, it's usually a good idea to make them all, especially as it's not *too* much extra work for quite a lot of potential gain, as detailed well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1924068)(The bit I'm referring to is about half-way down the answer and is headed Comparison Operators). This is largely because people expect them to work specifically for them all if it works for one. Also, it's good practice (as in for you to get better, not..Actually, both meanings).

**Data Types**

<strike>Salary and Budget, I'd tend to expect to be doubles, unless your specification has directly told you otherwise</strike> Proven to be wrong on this, as you were. (This next bit is personal preference) I'd personally use `std::string` whenever doing anything to do with strings in c++, but each to their own I guess, I don't know enough about `QString` to say otherwise.

**File Structure**

I've assumed that you have an employee.h as well as an employee.cpp and a main.cpp (or whatever you've called them), but I noticed the lack of [scope resolution operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator), and thought I should point it out. It's good for easy readability to keep your code in different files.

**Data Structures**

I'd not heard of a multi-map before reading this, but that seems pretty neat, and a good use of it on face value, although as far as I can tell, that is duplicating a lot of values, as you also have the employees in a `vector`. Maybe have your multi-map have a vector of pointers to employees? That way you're not duplicating data. Either that, or just store them in the multi-map

**General impression of the code**

It seems okay, basically. Good indentation, decent variable names and good commenting. Having not run it I can't speak to the functionality with respect to your assignment, but it was nice to read.

**Assumptions that you made**

Frankly, it depends. I wouldn't rely on employee names being unique, if it were a database, you'd have a unique key attached to the employee, and the manager coming before their subordinates depends on if you are defining the format of the file you're parsing through. If you are defining it, then your word is law and if it breaks, the person making the file messed up. Otherwise, you'll have to fall in line with the out of order input.

Comment: Is `const QString getName(){return name;}` considered to be good formatting in real world C++ ? In other languages, this would probably be recommended: `const QString getName() { return name; }`. Is it different in C++ ?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Take my opinion on "real world" c++ with a pinch of salt, as I'm the only one in my office who swears by it :P But it's personal preference with spacing really, unless you are following a style guide. I'd rather see the spaces myself.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Also, welcome to code-review. It's tricky asking good questions, and it takes practice. If an answer helps you and actually answers your question, hit the green tick next to it to accept it, although it's also usual to leave it 'open' for a bit before you accept (even a good) answer, as you might discourage a better one.

Comment: @Yann4 thanks for review. What i am still looking is, since  input is very open ended. Are my assumptions correct or there could be better way to solve it

Comment: `Salary and Budget, I'd tend to expect to be doubles`. **Absolutely Not**. Floating point values have rounding errors built into them. Never store currency values in them. Use a type that has absolute precision. Integer or some form of Decimal type.

Answer (score 4):

A few points on top of [@Yann4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51244/yann4)'s excellent review:

---

> ```
> Employee()
> {
>     name = QString();
>     mgrName = QString();
>     salary = 0;
>     budget =0;
> }
> ```

An employee without a name and manager? This doesn't seem to make sense. I recommend removing this constructor.

On a related note, it seems you could make some of the fields constant:

```
const QString name;
const QString mgrName;
const int salary;
int budget;
```

Constant fields are great, they make your class more robust.

---

You could initialize `budget` together with the other fields,
shortening the definition a little bit:

```
Employee(QString _name, QString _mgrName, int _salary): name(_name),
    mgrName(_mgrName), salary(_salary), budget(0) {}
```

---

You can return boolean expressions directly instead of this kind of ternary:

> ```
> return (emp1.budget <= emp2.budget ? true : false);
> ```

This is exactly the same, but short and sweet:

```
return emp1.budget <= emp2.budget;
```

---

It may be subjective, but this seems a bit tightly packed:

> ```
> const QString getName(){return name;}
> ```

Probably there is no standard for this, but I prefer this style, standard in other languages:

```
const QString getName() { return name; }
```

That is, put a space between `){`, and after `{` and before `}`.

Comment: Ta for the nice ego boost :P I think that having a default constructor is helpful, for debugging purposes, if nothing else. And I noticed after I replied in comments about the spacing that it wasn't @amdube that asked about it, but at least the (not-new) JuhaUntinen now knows about accepting answers (urk)...

Comment: @janos Default construcor is required because of calculateBudget(..) function else compilation fails

Comment: @Yann4 Good call, I rephrased that ;-) About default constructor, I think it's not good to pollute your interface with code for debugging or testing purposes. There should be no unnecessary elements, especially if they violate the logical integrity, like a name-less employee in this case.

Comment: There could be an empty position that's waiting to be filled? Although given that there are no setters, that might not be the case. I tend to like having default constructors, although that is where I have a constructor and an `Initialize()`. It sets it up in a known state which works well if you might be initializing to different levels.

Comment: @amdube I don't see in `calculateBudget` what requires a default constructor. The thing is, it doesn't make sense to require one, so you can probably refactor it to make it compile.

Comment: @Yann4 if you want to reserve some kind of placeholder for an empty position, a subclass of Employee would be cleaner.

Comment: @janos First line in the function. Yes code can be refactored  for it.

Comment: Yeah, although then you have to deal with type checking and stuff. Checking `name != empty` is pretty neat. I think it's beyond the scope of this app anyway, I was thinking out loud really.

Comment: Hello there.. I just wanted to chime in and remind you that comments are not the place for extended discussion. SE has their own [chat] for this ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Big Issues

The class should be able to read and write itself with `operator>>` and `operator<<` this makes writing loops for serialization trivial.

I hate getters/setters. They break encapsulation so badly. You pull stuff out do stuff and put it back into the class (use a method in the class to do it). Or you pull stuff out to print it. Write an object serializer `operator<<`.

If you are going to getters at least follow conventions (we will get to that).

I am not familiar with QTextStream and `atEnd()` call. But all other languages libraies return true only after you have tried to read past the end of the stream and thus.

```
while( <Check for End of File> )
{
}
```

[Is nearly always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/14065). If for some reason The QLib has decided to change this pattern they should be shot for making it work differently than every other language library out there.

The correct pattern is:

```
while( <Try and read object> )
{
    // Read worked so work with data
}
```

### Code comments in General?

Be very careful of using a prefix '_' on your identifiers; do you know the exact rules?

```
Employee(QString _name, QString _mgrName, int _salary):name(_name),
    mgrName(_mgrName), salary(_salary)
{
    budget = 0;
}
```

In the above code removing the underscores will not change the meaning and the code will still work perfectly.

Why not return references to the objects.

```
const QString getName(){return name;}
const QString getName() const{return name;}
```

This will cause a copy. Probably not a big deal for QLibs. But no point in doing extra work if you do not need to. Also it will be more consistent with all the other ugly getters and setters that are out in the wild. If the user of your code wants a local copy they just have to assign it to a variable.

I would have written like this:

```
QString&       getName()       {return name;}
QString const& getName() const {return name;}
```

A couple of issues with:

```
int budget(QMultiMap< QString,  Employee > & heirarchy, const QString& mgrName)
```

I am pretty sure this is wrong as you don't include the employees salary into the budget just the sum of his direct reports budgets.

Also it is very inefficient. It does a recursive calculation on the budget from the current employee all the way to the top (CEO). But it does this each time. So for large organizations with many levels you are re-calculating some budgets many time over.

I found where you add the salary to the budget:

```
void calculateBudget(QMultiMap< QString,  Employee > & heirarchy, QVector<Employee> & employees)
```

By doing it this way you are binding so many assumptions about order into your code (that are not necessary (you have all the data in memeory already)). This is just horrible.

Don't like this assumption:

```
// 3. a managers entry comes before any of his/her subordinates in input
```

Horrible loop reading a file:

```
     QTextStream in(&inputFile);
     while ( !in.atEnd() )
     {
          heirarchy.insert(paramList.at(1), emp);
          employees.push_back(emp);
     }
```

And we are keeping two data structures with exactly the same data in it. That seems a bit of a waste to me.

More standard way of writting this in C++ would have been:

```
     Employee e
     while(file >> e)
     {
         dataStructure.push_back(e); // or insert depending on the data structure.
     }
```

Which could then easily have been translated into:

```
     std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Employee>(file), std::istream_iterator<Employee>()
               std::back_inserter(dataStructure));
```

Much easier to read and understand whats going on. Moral of the story The emplyee should know how to read itself from a stream.

Not sure what is happening in the middle of the loop:

```
         if( i == 0)
         {
            //root or CEO
             heirarchy.insert("NOBODY", emp);
             i++;
         }
         else
         {
             heirarchy.insert(paramList.at(1), emp);
         }
```

Do you have to special case it here. The "NOBODY" is part of the input data.

This looks wrong:

```
Employee emp(paramList.at(0), paramList.at(1), paramList.at(2).toInt());
```

The input data is:

```
Abhishek Chauhan, 1200000, Ajay Joshi
```

Or

```
<Name>, <Salary>, <Manager>
```

So the order of values to the constructors looks wrong.